# Script for clearing Chrome or Firefox cache on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, firefox, windows-7, browser-cache

With Internet Explorer you can create a `.bat` file to clear the cache.

Example:

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

REM History:
REM RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1

REM Cookies:
REM RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2

REM Temp Internet Files:
REM RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8

REM Form Data:
REM RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16

REM Passwords:
REM RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32

REM OR

REM All:
rundll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351
```

Is there any way to do this with Chrome and/or Firefox ?

That is, with a `.bat` file or powershell script, running on a Windows machine, clear the cache of Chrome or Firefox?

I promise, I've looked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Chrome, you can clear the cache by deleting the contents of the Cache folder in `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache`. The history, cookies, and so on are SQLite database files in the parent folder, so you could get rid of them too if you wanted everything gone, like in your example with Internet Explorer:

```
$Items = @('Archived History',
            'Cache\*',
            'Cookies',
            'History',
            'Login Data',
            'Top Sites',
            'Visited Links',
            'Web Data')
$Folder = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
$Items | % { 
    if (Test-Path "$Folder\$_") {
        Remove-Item "$Folder\$_" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll let this question sit for a bit, and the mark the answer.

Comment: Works well.  Chrome has to be shut down, FYI, for future readers.

Comment: How to run this ?

Comment: @Invader 1. Copy the code. 2. Run PowerShell (open the Start menu and type `PowerShell` if you don't have another way to get to it). 3. Paste the code into PowerShell. 4. Press Enter.

Comment: Can this be placed in a batch file xxx.bat ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my variant of cleaning script which contains improved version of [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1958726/eric-eskildsen)'s script.
It includes Chrome, Chromium and IE directories altogether. 
`$DaysToDelete` variable determines how many days cache data is to be stored on machine.

```
$DaysToDelete = 1

$temporaryIEDir = "C:\users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*" ## Remove all files and folders in user's Temporary Internet Files. 
$cachesDir = "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches"  ## Remove all IE caches. 
$cookiesDir = "C:\Documents and Settings\*\Cookies\*" ## Delets all cookies. 
$locSetDir = "C:\Documents and Settings\*\Local Settings\Temp\*"  ## Delets all local settings temp 
$locSetIEDir = "C:\Documents and Settings\*\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\*"   ## Delets all local settings IE temp 
$locSetHisDir = "C:\Documents and Settings\*\Local Settings\History\*"  ## Delets all local settings history

Get-ChildItem $temporaryIEDir, $cachesDir, $cookiesDir, $locSetDir, $locSetIEDir, $locSetHisDir -Recurse -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.CreationTime -lt $(Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysToDelete)) } | remove-item -force -Verbose -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$DaysToDelete = 7

$crLauncherDir = "C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Chromium\User Data\Default"
$chromeDir = "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
$chromeSetDir = "C:\Users\*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"

$Items = @("*Archived History*", "*Cache*", "*Cookies*", "*History*", "*Login Data*", "*Top Sites*", "*Visited Links*", "*Web Data*")

$items | ForEach-Object {
$item = $_ 
Get-ChildItem $crLauncherDir, $chromeDir, $chromeSetDir -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Where-Object { ($_.CreationTime -lt $(Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysToDelete)) -and $_ -like $item} | ForEach-Object -Process { Remove-Item $_ -force -Verbose -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Powershell that kills chrome and clean all of chrome's profiles of the user:

```
taskkill /F /IM "chrome.exe"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$Items = @('Archived History',
            'Cache\*',
            'Cookies',
            'History',
            #'Login Data',
            'Top Sites',
            'Visited Links'
            #'Web Data'
            )
$Folders = Get-ChildItem "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome\User Data" | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq "Default" -or $_.Name -like "Profile*"}
$Folders | ForEach-Object {
    $tmp = $_
    $Items | ForEach-Object { 
        if((Test-Path -Path "$tmp\$_" )){
            Remove-Item "$tmp\$_" 
        }
    }
}
```